# Azure YAML Pipelines: How to refer a project and repo in another project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am in an Organization ABC, It has three Azure DevOps projects, namely A, B, and C. Everything is under Azure Repos that means we are not using GitHub.

I am trying to perform a checkout in Project C the repos from project A and B. Every project will have its ow microservices but Shared Platform Services will automate what needs to be deployed into AKS.

Problem Statement: I get error like below when I am trying to checkout repos from projects A and B in Project C. Snippet is as below:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: microservice-a
      type: git
      name: 'InPlaceCommunications/microservice-a'
      ref: master

    - repository: microservice-b
      type: git
      name: 'Project B/microservice-b'
      ref: master
```

However, I get error as below:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier microservice-a does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
```

Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

I do note that I have full permissions to clone the repo myself it is just not happening on the Pipeline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier microservice-a does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

Based on the error message, you need to check the following two points:

1. Check if the option **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines** is **disable** in **Project C -> Project Settings -> Settings**. You need to disable this option.

[image]

2. Check if the Service Account: **Project Collection Build Service (OrganizationName)** has the Read Permission in **Project A/B -> Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target repos -> Security**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin! I did the first one and it has worked like a charm. My local repos from Project C however are giving me errors like below:

remote: TF200016: The following project does not exist: Project C. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I figured it out what is the issue. Nothing to do with the solution you proposed. One of team member removed the space in Azure DevOps project hence I am getting the error!